# Determining curve in the complex plane

Tags: curves, plane-curves

Question: 
Determine the curve in the complex plane that is determined by $ \lvert z-3\rvert + \lvert z+3\rvert =\lvert 10-3\rvert$

So far I have
$ \lvert z-3\rvert + \lvert z+3\rvert =7$

$ \lvert (x+iy)-3\rvert + \lvert (x+iy)+3\rvert =7$   ; Since $z=x+iy$

However, now I do not know how to proceed with this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rearrange, square, rearrange, square, and rearrange one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically speaking $$ \lvert z-3\rvert + \lvert z+3\rvert =\lvert 10-3\rvert$$ describes the set of point on the complex plane whose sum of distances from the points $3$ and $-3$ is a constant $7$

This is an ellipse with foci at $-3$ and $3$ with major diameter of $2a=7$

The equation of the ellipse is $$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ where $a=3.5$ and $b= \sqrt {3.5^2-3^2}$

Comment: I think we were supposed to get to the equation of the ellipse by evaluating what was given. Do you know how that is done?

Comment: @PopcornFiend  $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} =1 $ where $a=3.5$, $b= \sqrt {3.5^2-9}$